# jsPlumb flowchart connector layout direction change in 5x

Tags: jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb 5x for a flowchart application. Used packages are @jsplumb/connector-flowchart and @jsplumb/browser-ui. I decided to use flowchart connectors. I couldn't find a way to change the connector layout.

[image: new layout]

Is there any way to change the style so that new layout looks like the above?

Current connector layout:

[image: current connector layout]

Currently, I define connectors inside `instance.connect` method [as described here](https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/lib/connectors#flowchart-connector):

```
connector: {
          type: FlowchartConnector.type,
          options: {
            stub: [10, 20],
            gap: 1,
            cornerRadius: 2,
            alwaysRespectStubs: true
          }
        },
```

The layout works as intended on jsPlumb 2x with the following code:

```
connector: ["Flowchart", {
          stub: [10, 20],
          gap: 1,
          cornerRadius: 2,
          alwaysRespectStubs: true
        }],
```

Is there any way to change flowchart connectors layouts on 5x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here might be the anchors you're using - it doesn't look like your edges are going from a `Bottom` edge to a `Top` edge.

You can read up on anchors on this page:  https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/lib/anchors

To specify `Top` and `Bottom` you can either provide those values in the defaults:

https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/lib/defaults

or in a `connect` call.

it is possible that in the migration from 2.x to 5.x you've got an `Anchor` or `Anchors` default somewhere, but note that all defaults in 5.x are now lower case: `anchor` / `anchors` etc.